# C# redirect inside timerevent

Tags: c#, redirect, timer

I have a timer setup to fire 4 seconds after a user hits a button except in the OnTimedEvent I need to redirect users to another webpage.  Here's what I have so far:

In the `onClick` Event of the button:

```
System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
aTimer.Interval = 4000;
aTimer.Enabled = true;
```

Then in the `OnTimed Event()` I have:

```
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Account/DeleteAccount.aspx");            
}
```

I have also tried

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Account/DeleteAccount.aspx");
```

in the `OnTimedEvent` with no luck.

Comment: Is the event even firing in debug? Response.Redirect is a straightforward function. What other variables are there, is this in an ASCX, or firing under an account with lowered permissions?

Comment: Are you trying to redirect the user that clicked the button, or are you trying to redirect future users that access the page after the 4 seconds have elapsed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have emitted a page, it's too late to send a redirect: the response has already been sent, so the response object you have is no longer valid.

Instead, you'll need to deal with it either in client-side script code with something like

```
window.setTimeout(function() { window.location.href = "~/Account/DeleteAccount.aspx"; }, 4000);
```

or by setting a Refresh header in the response to tell the client side that it will need to load a different page at that time.

Also, instantiating a Timer from inside a page like that is probably a bad idea -- besides the fact that it's holding an invalid response object, the timer will hang around even if a visitor closes the page, and it's a fairly expensive object in terms of system resources.

Source: [asp.net timer and response.redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384847/asp-net-timer-and-response-redirect)

Comment: Another option would be emitting a meta refresh tag into the document. eg, <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="4;url=/Account/DeleteAccount.aspx">

Answer (score 0):

Standard asynchronous models don't really work so well in the context of a single web response.  When you finish setting up the timer the method you did it in will continue executing, which means it will finish building the response and then it will send it (it will have time to do all of that in 4 second, in all probability).  Because of this, by the time the timer fires the response has already been sent and ended.  HTTP is designed that once a request is ended you can't send more, it will just end up being ignored.

You have several choices.  One is to ensure that the response isn't sent for 4 seconds. (This Means rather than using a timer, just use something like `Thread.Sleep` that blocks to wait 4 seconds.)  Another is to let the response be sent, but to have JavaScript or other client side code that sets a timer and does the redirect in 4 seconds.  The second option would be needed if you have a page that you want to render while waiting, the first would be best if you just want the user to watch the browser spin while the server is doing...something.

If your goal is not to just wait 4 seconds, but to run some long running task and this timer is an attempt to wait for it to finish, then you need to change that design.  In a web environment you will be better off running the long running task (assuming long running is a second or two, not like minutes/hours) directly in the current thread because you *want* to block the thread from continuing on with it's business.  If you spin up a new thread to do work you can't rely on ever being able to affect the response (so it's okay to new up a thread if it never affects the response).  If your request is *really* long, or you want to show something to the client before it's done, then you'll want to use AJAX to send a response before the long running task finishes, and then have it keep sending new requests to the server so that it can update the page once the long running task has generated it's results.  [Here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETBackgroundWorker-dda8d7b6/view/SourceCode) is a cool example demonstrating this technique.

Comment: Just a heads up; `Thread.Sleep` radically reduces the number of simultanious requests the server can handle, cause it eats up the ThreadPool threads.

Comment: You need to do something to block the request for that amount of time, or you need to have the client generate a new request after the desired amount of time.  If you block the server, yes, it will kill performance.  It's hard to say what should be done without more details.  If the waiting is just waiting, then blocking the server is the wrong choice to start with.  If the waiting is waiting on a long running process, just run that long running process in the processing thread rather than spinning up a new thread.

Comment: @JimS. In that case, you should just not do it in another thread.  In winforms you always want long running tasks in another thread to not freeze the UI, in a web environment you *want* to block the UI because you can't update it if you don't block it.

Comment: If scale is a consideration I wouldn't block.  Use one of the async patterns instead. For asp.net http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx, for mvc http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx.  This allows the thread serving the request to continue working while waiting on whatever IO would normally block you (a potentially different thread will finish the request when the IO is done).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand (and I might be entirely wrong on this part) this code makes no sense. The `HttpContext.Current` makes me guess this is ASP.NET related, and seeing as the code is in c# I'm also guessing that it's server code.

Under normal sircumstances (without using a timer), if you do a redirect on the server; this is aproximally what happens:

1. The client sends a request to the server
2. The server runs the page lifesycle
3. At some point during this sycle, a `Response.Redirect` is called
4. The server returns http-headers and information to the client that it should navigate to the url given to the `Response.Redirect` method.
5. The connection is closed.

Now, after point 4 there is no way to tell the browser to navigate anywhere else (if you don't use some form of server-sent events, long pooling or COMET in general).

So, here comes the problem, instead of calling `Response.Redirect` at point 3, you start a timer. What happens than is this:

1. The timer is started
2. The server finnishes the Page Life-Sycle, and returns content to the client.
3. The connection is closed.

And some time later

1. The timer ticks in.
2. You try to send "redirect" to the client, but the client is already long gone.

Unless you need to run some other server-side code when the button is clicked, this can probably be achieved most easily using javascript onclick. Something like this: `window.setTimeout(function(){window.location = 'newLocation.aspx....';}, 4000/*4 sec*/);`